# What do I do when an immigrant does not want to show his papers?

Tags: papers-please

In the game, [Papers, Please](http://dukope.com/), you play as an immigration inspector.

Normally, the immigrants and visitors will show you their documents and papers once they've been called to the counter.

This one didn't:
[image]
This is Day 3.

I'm pretty much stuck with this man until the end of my shift. How do I get this man to leave the counter?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Turns out I had to highlight the discrepancies (lower right "red !" button), by highlighting the part of the rule book where it says everyone had to have a passport to enter, and highlighting the area of the counter where one should place his papers. This will show an 'interrogate' option (lower-middle part of the counter) allowing one to continue.

Comment: +1 I love the comment in your question that links to this question because it answers your question... if you know what I mean.